# is it possible to register only a view in django admin and not any model? using django 3.2 version

Tags: django, view

The requirement is to register views in the django admin interface just like the models, which will serve as hyperlink and execute some code in the views to display some on-screen data. Is it possible. Looks like adminplus doesnt work with this version of django for t he same. Any other tool to serve this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to just modify admin templates if you just want to add some custom links:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

If you need some code to be executed you can even overwrite the default admin site and change views, add context data etc.:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site

or overwrite for just one "pseudo" Model change_view() and changelist_view():

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#other-methods